# Creating a List View and Thumbnail view in Drupal 7 view

Tags: views

I created a view but I am hoping to create two possible viewings of it.

Basically, it's showing it in either `List View` or `Thumbnail View`. Now, one option would be to create two views and showing one of them by default and hiding the other; hence toggling each when the button is pressed. But I was hoping to find some more efficient less resource intensive solution.

### Thumbnail view

[image]

### List view

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could create one view with 2 pages or blocks depending on how you are setting up your view. Then have one show list view and the other show thumbnail view. You could then use tabs to switch between the 2 views.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @n30r3b3l. The easiest way to do this is to create multiple "displays" within a single view. To do this, simply click the add [image] "+ Add" button in the top left are of the views edit page. You can rename each display. You will need to watch out for one thing, though. When you edit things in one display, the default setting is that the change will affect all displays. [image]

You can override this setting on the edit form. Like so: [image]